Get injected attribute directive from another directive
I've have two nested custom directives on third-party components. I can't find a way to inject or access the actual directive (with custom functions/logic) instead of the base component. Here is a sample code schema:
<tp-parent my-parent-directive>
 <tp-child my-child-directive></tp-child>
 <tp-child my-child-directive></tp-child>
</tp-parent>

And the directives:
@Directive({
  selector: '[my-parent-directive]'
})
export class MyParentDirective{

  constructor(@Self() target: TpParentComponent) {
    // Custom stuff...
  }
  
  parentFcn() {
    // Extended functionality...
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[my-child-directive]'
})
export class MyChildDirective{

  constructor(@Self() target: TpChildComponent, @Host() parentComp: TpParentComponent, @Host() parentDir: MyParentDirective) {
    // Custom stuff...
  }
}

When running, the parentComp variable in the child directive correctly injects the parent component and parentDir is always null. My goal is to call parentFcn() from the child directive, but I don't have access to it. How can I correctly access both the parent component and directive from the child, or even convert/get one from the other anywhere?
Thank you for your help.
